# How to install openbravo ERP in windows 7?

Tags: installation, erp, openbravo

How to install and setup openbravo ERP in windows 7 ? Which package I should download ? I have no idea of it. Please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through this [**link**](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/ERP_2.50:Openbravo_ERP_Installation/Custom_Installation).

It provides you with the complete information regarding the System requirements, Setting up environment and Downloading the source code and then building it.

Hope this helps.